# How to get Language using WPGlobus

Tags: php, wordpress, multilingual

I am using `WPGlobus WordPress plugin` on a bilingual (Spanish and English) website but I don´t know how to filter recent post for language using `WPGglobus` with `PHP`?

With `WPML` I´ve used some like:

```
<?php if( qtrans_getLanguage() == 'es'){ 
    // My Spanish Content here
} else{
    //My Content English here
} ?>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
WPGlobus::Config()->language
```

to get the current language and

```
WPGlobus_Core::text_filter( $text, $language )
```

to get the relevant part.

Or – you can just

```
$text = apply_filters( 'the_title', $text );
```

without dealing with any specific functions.

Comment: Thank you Ivan, This work with $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );  ???